# Ruby Aws::Route53::Client filter for objects without tags

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-route53

I am gathering up untagged health checks using the ruby Aws::Route53::Client with [two](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/Route53/Client.html#list_tags_for_resources-instance_method) [functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/Route53/Client.html#list_health_checks-instance_method) and then tagging them.  Right now I am gathering all health checks, then filtering for ones without tags.  Is there a filter I can used to directly gather all the health checks without tags?

Heres the snip of my code that currently does this:

```
...
    # lookup checks, list_tags_for_resources has a max search of 10 items
    checks_search = client.list_health_checks(marker: marker, max_items: 10)
    ids = checks_search.to_h[:health_checks].map {|check| check[:id]}
    list_check_tags = client.list_tags_for_resources({
      resource_type: "healthcheck", 
      resource_ids: ids, 
    }).to_h

    untagged = list_check_tags[:resource_tag_sets].select{|check| check[:tags].empty?}.map {|check| check[:resource_id]}
...
```

At the least is there a way to run [list_tags_for_resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/Route53/Client.html#list_tags_for_resources-instance_method) while only filtering for resources without any tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do something *within* the list_tags_for_resources method to make it returned a filtered list, you'd have to monkey patch the method. You could do something like this (untested, probably incorrect, but shows the principle):

```
module Aws::Route53
  class Client < Seahorse::Client::Base
    def list_tags_for_resource(params = {}, options = {})
      req = build_request(:list_tags_for_resource, params)
      req.send_request(options)[:resource_tag_sets].select{|check| check[:tags].empty?}.map {|check| check[:resource_id]}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: So it seems that this is unsupported on any default Aws::Route53 functions.  This may go outside the scope of the original question, but would it be possible to filter for health checks without tags using [Aws::ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI::Client.get_resources-instance_method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI/Client.html#get_resources-instance_method)? If so what would the correct `resource_type_filters` arn be? I've been attempting to use `"route53:::healthcheck"` but I think that is incorrect.

Comment: Created a health check to play with it:  `resource_type_filters: ["route53:healthcheck"]` worked for me (region: us-east-1).

Comment: + as the documentation indicates, this does only return tagged resources (so it will not work to simplify your code)